# Leaflet Layergroups in loop

Tags: javascript, leaflet, layer

Hi i have this code that from txt file create markers on image map. And i want to add layer control to hide or show different markers with L.control.layers now with this code it hide all markers. Is it possible to split markers by coordinates into groups ? Thanks

```
var stringData = $.ajax({
    url: "a.txt",
    async: false
}).responseText;
//Split values of string data                                                                    
var stringArray = stringData.split("\n");
var arrayLength = stringArray.length ;

var layerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var x = $.trim(stringArray[i].split(",")[0]);
    var y = $.trim(stringArray[i].split(",")[1]);
    var img2 = $.trim(stringArray[i].split(",")[2]);

    var circle = L.circle([x,y], {
        color: 'red',
        fillColor: '#f03',
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        radius: 2,
    }).addTo(map);
    circle.url = img2
    circle.on('click', function(){
    window.location = (this.url);
    });
    layerGroup.addLayer(circle);
}
var overlayMaps = {
    "Normal": layerGroup,
    "Elite": layerGroup,
    "Ultimate": layerGroup
};
L.control.layers(null, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

a.txt

```
-146.4375, 183.0625, img/img1.png
-104.5, 182.75, img/img2.png,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course. Just create 3 layerGroups. In your loop, you have to add a condition to add your circles to either of them.

```
var layerGroup1 = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
var layerGroup2 = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
var layerGroup3 = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);


for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var x = $.trim(stringArray[i].split(",")[0]);
    var y = $.trim(stringArray[i].split(",")[1]);
    var img2 = $.trim(stringArray[i].split(",")[2]);

    var circle = L.circle([x,y], {
        color: 'red',
        fillColor: '#f03',
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        radius: 2,
    });
    circle.url = img2
    circle.on('click', function(){
    window.location = (this.url);
    });


    switch(img2) {
       case "img/img1.png":
           circle.addTo(layerGroup1);
           break;
       case "img/img2.png":
           circle.addTo(layerGroup2);
           break;
       case "img/img3.png":
           circle.addTo(layerGroup3);
           break;
       default:
           break;
    }
  }

var overlayMaps = {
    "Normal": layerGroup1,
    "Elite": layerGroup2,
    "Ultimate": layerGroup3
};
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/f8azOmaz1ITLZiKgfHWt?p=preview

Comment: It works with this logic: if you hide any of the groups it will hide the marker, if you show any of the groups it will show the marker. So, if you have the 2 groups showing and then you hide one, the marker will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

something like this ?

```
var layerGroup1 = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
var layerGroup2 = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
var layerGroup3 = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var x = $.trim(stringArray[i].split(",")[0]);
    var y = $.trim(stringArray[i].split(",")[1]);
    var img2 = $.trim(stringArray[i].split(",")[2]);

    var circle = L.circle([x,y], {
        color: 'red',
        fillColor: '#f03',
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        radius: 2,
    }).addTo(map).addTo(layerGroup1);
    circle.url = img2
    circle.on('click', function(){
    window.location = (this.url);
    });

  if((img2 === "img/img2.png")||(img2 === "img/img3.png")){
       var circle2 = L.circle([x,y], {
        color: 'red',
        fillColor: '#f03',
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        radius: 2,
    }).addTo(map).addTo(layerGroup2);
  }

}
var overlayMaps = {
    "Normal": layerGroup1,
    "Elite": layerGroup2,
    "Ultimate": layerGroup3
};
L.control.layers(null, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

Comment: you just have to add the circles to layerGroups (not to the map). I have edited the answer. I have used a switch which is ideal when you implement this kind of logic